# magento 2 third party module installation through composer

Tags: magento2, composer

I'm developing and trying to install a module through composer in Magento. My module's composer.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "amit/test",
  "description": "N/A",
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6",
    "magento/module-store": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-backend": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-cron": "100.1.*",
    "magento/framework": "100.1.*"
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "100.1.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Amit\\Test\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

When I'm running command `composer require amit/test` from root of my project it gives error

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Could not find package amit/test at any version for your minim
>   um-stability (alpha). Check the package spelling or your
>   minimum-stability

**Question:** As my module is still not in a packages repository such as packagist.org, or packages.magento.com, is it compulsory to upload it to a VCS like github in order to install it through composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be in some kind of repository and you have to define it in the "repositories" section of the project's composer.json.

For possible repository types see: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md

A VCS (i.e. Git) is the best choice, but it does not have to be publicly accessible (i.e. GitHub)